# std::vector of function pointers

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I have a vector of function pointers.

```
class GameState : public AppState{
private:
    void level1();
    std::vector<void (*)()> levelFunctions;
};
```

How do I push things into this vector? I have tried

```
void GameState::level1(){
    levelFunctions.push_back(&GameState::level1);
}
```

and others but I get compile errors each time.

Comment: `&GameState::level1` is a member function. You can't store it as a normal pointer. Use `std::function` and `bind`.

Comment: Could you give an example as an answer? I have not used either of these before.

Comment: `std::function<void()> func = std::bind(&GameState::level1, this);`

Comment: You could make a vector of *member* function pointers, e.g. `std::vector<void (GameState::*)()>`.

Comment: @Pubby "std has no member bind". I am using VS10, does that not include it?

Comment: @pighead10 `std::function` and `std::bind` are part of C++ 11 and are very similar to `boost::function` and `boost::bind` which you can download and use.

Comment: Using Kerrek SB's solution. It's okay, I never have to go back to this code after 5 hours.

Comment: Er... How do I call the function (using member function pointers)?

Comment: @pighead10: `(object.*mem_fun_ptr)()` or `(pointer->*mem_fun_ptr)()`